# external css stylesheet looks different in ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, stylesheet

I'm pointing to the css that is being used by our client.
The site i'm working on and the site they have are meant to look the same/similar in terms of header/footer etc.

It's working well on the whole, however in ie8 the site for the client looks very different to the site i'm working on.

When I look the that particular stylesheet in developer tools (IE) then view that css, I can clearly see some things missing in the one for the site I'm working on.

How can that be? how can i fix?

Thanks

Comment: What properties are missing? Are you sure they're supported in IE8?

Comment: Depends if you are viewing the site in the IE8 too. If it looks different in your IE8 to their IE8, then it is strange. If you are viewing the site in Chrome or in other browser then there can be some compatibillity issues with particular CSS properties, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Could there be server settings ( IIS or apache  ) that might have a setting that instructs the site to behave like IE7 Compatibility View ?

Comment: @Fallup yes i'm viewing both in ie8, one example background-image in mine appears as:"url("../../SiteElements/Images/body.png")", and in theres its url("http://www.example.com/../../SiteElements/Images/body.png")

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8">  here insert stylesheets <![endif]-->
```

Comment: What kind of answer is this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check "**Compatibility View**" in IE from this path:

> Tools > Compatibility View Setting

[more info](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/compatibility-view)